# Displaying Rows conditional on values of two columns - R

Tags: r

| treat | age | education | black | hispanic | married | nodegree | re74 | re75 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1: | 0 | 23 | 10 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 2: | 0 | 26 | 12 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 3: | 0 | 22 | 9 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 4: | 0 | 18 | 9 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |

I'm trying to only display data where either `re74==0` or `re75==0` or both are equal to zero, which implies that I'm disregarding the rows where both are equal to one.

Comment: What have you tried so far that didn't work? There are many questions on SO already about subsetting data—which ones haven't worked already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(¬_¬)df <- data.frame(
...   stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
...              treat = c("1:", "2:", "3:", "4:"),
...                age = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L),
...          education = c(23L, 26L, 22L, 18L),
...              black = c(10L, 12L, 9L, 9L),
...           hispanic = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 1L),
...            married = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L),
...           nodegree = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L),
...               re74 = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 1L),
...               re75 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L)
... )
(¬_¬)df[df$re74==0 |df$re75==0, ]
  treat age education black hispanic married nodegree re74 re75
2    2:   0        26    12        0       0        0    0    0
3    3:   0        22     9        1       0        0    1    0
4    4:   0        18     9        1       0        0    1    0
```

Comment: You can also use subset  to select rows where both re74 and re75 are both  equal to 1:   ```df2 <- df[!(df$re74 == 1 & df$re75 == 1 ), ]```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% filter(re74 == 0 | re75 == 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `subset`

```
 subset(df, re74 == 0 | re75 == 0)
```